# certificate issues for visual studio application

Tags: c#, .net, code-signing

I have an old project created by a set of previous devs.  This project has a code signing cert and its now expired. I have made my changes to the app and there is directions from the previous team on how to build the new code signing cert.

However, nothing is working.

The directions they left are

Open up developer console for the version of VS installed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.110).aspx
MakeCert.exe -n "CN=domain.com" -pe -e 01/01/2020 -$ individual -sv "C:\Projects\TEST\3.0\Certificate\MykeyNameFile.kf" -sr localmachine -len 2048 "C:\Projects\TEST\3.0\Certificate\TESTSelfSigned.cer" -r

Keyfile password: myPassword

-This will copy the public and private key information into the a pfx file that is required for signing the click once.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672(v=vs.85).aspx
pvk2pfx -pvk "C:\Projects\TEST\3.0\Certificate\MykeyNameFile.kf" -pi myPassword -spc C:\Projects\TEST\3.0\Certificate\TESTSelfSigned.cer -pfx C:\Projects\TEST\3.0\Certificate\TESTClickOnce.pfx

The first command runs correctly.  The second command for pvk2pfx spits out the following.

Usage:
pvk2pfx -pvk  [-pi ] -spc 
[-pfx  [-po ] [-f]]

```
    -pvk <pvk-file>  - input PVK file name.
    -spc <spc-file>  - input SPC file name.
    -pfx <pfx-file>  - output PFX file name.
    -pi <pvk-pswd>   - PVK password.
    -po <pfx-pswd>   - PFX password; same as -pi if not given.
    -f               - force overwrite existing PFX file.

    if -pfx option is not given, an export wizard will pop up. in
    this case, options -po and -f are ignored.
```

Every variation I have tried has resulted in this and I have found no good examples that are any different.

Anyone else have similar issues?  How did you get around this?